# Arduino shows odd behaviour with LED output in loop

Tags: c++, arduino

Hi I am having a little trouble understanding the behaviour of what would seem a very simple issue.

I have 4 LED's and resistors linked up, with a push button. The idea is that I press the button and the LEDS light up sequentially, turning the previous one off.

This works fine, until it is time to restart the loop from the beginning where everything is ok in serial monitor, but the LEDS barely light up except number 4 which lights up normally.

Here is my code:

```
const int buttonPin = 6;
const int ledPin1 =  2;
const int ledPin2 =  3;
const int ledPin3 =  4;
const int ledPin4 =  5;

int buttonState = 0;
int pressed = 0;

void setup() {
    {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();
  Serial.println ("Starting up");
  }
  pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop()
  {
  if(digitalRead(buttonPin)==HIGH)     
    {
    if(pressed==0)
      {
      pressed=1; 
      switch(buttonState)
        {
      case 0:
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
        buttonState++;
      break; 
      case 1:
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
        Serial.println ("1");
        buttonState++;
      break; 
      case 2:
        digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
        pinMode(ledPin1, LOW);
        Serial.println ("2");
        buttonState++;
      break; 
       case 3:
        digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);
        pinMode(ledPin2, LOW);
        Serial.println ("3");
        buttonState++;
      break; 
      case 4:
        digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
        pinMode(ledPin3, LOW);
        Serial.println ("4");
        buttonState++;
      break; 
      case 5:
        digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW);
        Serial.println ("off");
        buttonState=0;
        return;
        }
      }
    }
  else
    {
    pressed=0;
    }
}
```

Hope some of you more intelligent folks can shed some light on this unusual behaviour.

BTW I am VERY new to arduino programming so please take it easy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, don't think it's a debounce issue though, it's almost as though the voltage is being sucked down on LEDS 1, 2 & 3, but not 4. They are barely visible but working fine otherwise.

Comment: @kentaro's answer below is correct. Here's a link to the [pinMode()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.PinMode) docs. Generally you only need to set the `pinMode` in you setup code

Comment: Additionally to @Kentaro's correct answer, some debouncing might be helpful. Simply try a `delay(5);` if you notice  more than one `Serial.println` output per button press. No problem if you simply add it to every loop run.

Comment: Added a debounce and things are a lot smoother, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You want to understand the difference between `pinMode()` and `digitalWrite()` functions.

`pinMode(pin, mode)` configures the specified pin to behave either as an input or an output. [(doc)](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/pinmode/) 
`digitalWrite(pin, value)` writes a HIGH or a LOW value to a digital pin. [(doc)](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/)

In your switch statement, you are changing `pinMode` from `OUTPUT` to `INPUT`.

```cpp
pinMode(ledPin1, LOW)
```

is the same as

```cpp
pinMode(ledPin1, INPUT)
```

because `LOW` and `INPUT` are both defined as `0x00`.

When you change the pin mode to `INPUT`, you can no longer turn on your LED by calling `digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH)`.

LED 4 works because you don't call `pinMode(ledPin4, LOW)` anywhere.

I think you wanted to call `digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW)` instead of `pinMode(ledPin1, LOW)` in the switch statement.

Comment: OMG I can't believe I missed that lol. That was EXACTLY the issue. Thanks so much for that, and I think that will be a lesson I don't forget in a hurry lol